# Why are questions with little requester effort penalized?

Tags: discussion, questions, downvotes

One thing I've noticed in the Stack community is that people who use this site don't seem to like questions where the poster of the question hasn't put in a lot of effort before asking the question. That sounds like a strange complaint, but hear me out.

Last week, I posed a question that was a very specific problem and more design related, and could have been given some great answers by people, but instead it was repeatedly down-voted because people thought I was *taking the easy way out* and taking advantage of the site. I deleted the question out of frustration so won't be referencing it here.

From my perspective, the reason I posted the question that I did was to accomplish two things:

1. Understand the thinking behind good solutions to the problem *before I started* coding it
2. More importantly, help document the specific issue on Stack so people searching for similar issues in the future would be able to find good solutions to the problem

Many of the questions I post on Stack Overflow actually have number two as a motive. If I add a question into the ether which hasn't been asked before, and people answer it, or I answer it down the road, then it's there for future reference. If I don't, nothing good is done for anyone.

Whether I've put any prior effort into the solution or not, *no one is forced to answer the question*, so there's no harm done in asking. Now, usually I do what I can to solve my issues before I ask, but sometimes I'd like to just put something up on the site and see what people with more expertise think. To me, that makes sense as something which should be a norm on Stack.

Instead, people seem to be trigger-happy with down-votes on Stack, to the point where I *really don't understand what constitutes a good or bad question*, or at least I don't agree with what constitutes a good or bad question. A lot of the time the votes I get seem to be completely arbitrary or based on reasoning I just don't agree with.

Can someone please explain what it is I don't understand about Stack so I can start using it properly?

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the deleted post so 10K+ users can have a look at it? It should be in your profile under "recently deleted posts" (but I don't know if that's still there since the redesign). It's possible there are other issues with the post, not related to your level of effort (or the issue was something closely related to, but subtly different than, level of effort).

Comment: "Whether I've put any prior effort into the solution or not, no one is forced to answer the question, so there's no harm done in asking." Whether you've asked me to send you an email or not, no-one is forcing you to read your emails, so there's no harm in everyone sending you spam, right? There is a cost to poor questions, in terms of quality dilution.

Comment: *"Why are questions with little requester effort penalized?"* - why wouldn't they be? The down vote tool-tip starts *"This question does not show any research effort..."*

Comment: *"people who use this site don't seem to like questions where the poster of the question hasn't put in a lot of effort before asking the question"* Yep, absolutely right.

Answer (score 39):

> Whether I've put any prior effort into the solution or not, no one is forced to answer the question, so there's no harm done in asking.

Yes, there is. The site gets littered with zero-effort questions that could have been answered with a simple search. We're not here to replace Google, we're here to complement it. If what you're looking for can already be easily found, then there's no need to post about it again and again.

Comment: One of the reasons that Bill's answe ris important is because users use Stack Overflow [as a form of procrastination](http://blog.codinghorror.com/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect/) instead of actually attempting to solve their problem. It's easy to procrastinate, and it's even easier when you've got a shiny content generator like Stack Overflow. If you're a new user, resist this urge. Try something. When it breaks, try to fix it. If you can't, ask us about it.

Answer (score 20):

Problems of design are out of scope for SO.  They're in scope in Programmers, but not SO.

The amount of effort isn't a problem, rather your question was off topic for the site.

As for you simply disagreeing with how people choose to vote, there really isn't anything you can do about that.  The community has its own set of values, you can either conform to them, or choose to participate in other communities that are more in line with your values.  Both are perfectly fine options.  SO isn't for everyone, and it doesn't try to be.